# Why more codes do not work with PIC microcontroller when RAM and ROM have free spaces

Tags: microcontroller, pic, c

I code for reading EEPROM and edit those EEPROM data and work with those data. Normally I am coding something and upload to PIC and check that code.

When I am code more than some point it is not working. I connected LCD with PIC it also shows all pixels ON. when I remove codes in somewhere then again working. When codes are high PIC not working. When codes are less then PIC working.

But when I compiled it shows PIC have free ROM and RAM spaces.

[image: massage]

I am using 4Mhz crystal oscillator and PIC18F4550 microcontroller. I am using MikroC for coding.

Why did this happen in Hardware?

Protues Simulation:

When I use protues simulation for this code it's given me following error.

```
[PIC18 STACK] PC=0x098E. Stack overflow is forcing device reset. [U1]
```

My code:

```
     // LCD module connections
    sbit LCD_RS at RD0_bit;
    sbit LCD_EN at RD1_bit;
    sbit LCD_D4 at RD4_bit;
    sbit LCD_D5 at RD5_bit;
    sbit LCD_D6 at RD6_bit;
    sbit LCD_D7 at RD7_bit;

    sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISD0_bit;
    sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISD1_bit;
    sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISD4_bit;
    sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISD5_bit;
    sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISD6_bit;
    sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISD7_bit;
    // End LCD module connections
    unsigned short shedno=0,i=0,shedc=0,streg,lsreg,rang,x;
    unsigned count=0,reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5, reg6,sttime=1000;
    char shednon[4]="",countn[6]="",stregn[4]="",lsregn[4]="",regval[6]="",ntrel1[6]="",ntrel2[6]="",ntrel3[6]="",ntrel4[6]="",ntrel5[6]="",ntrel6[6]="";


     void findshed(short sno){
        shedno = EEPROM_Read(0x00);
        shedno = 256 - shedno;
        shedno = shedno + sno;
        ByteToStr(shedno, shednon);

        streg = 6*shedno+4;
        lsreg = streg + 5;
        ByteToStr(streg, stregn);
        ByteToStr(lsreg, lsregn);
     }

      void shedrelay(){
              rang =0;
              for(x=streg; x<=lsreg; x++){
                regval[rang] = EEPROM_Read(x);
                Delay_ms(100);
                if(rang < 6){
                rang++;
                }
              }
              reg1 =  regval[0]+sttime;
              reg2 =  regval[1]+sttime;
              reg3 =  regval[2]+sttime;
              reg4 =  regval[3]+sttime;
              reg5 =  regval[4]+sttime;
              reg6 =  regval[5]+sttime;
              Wordtostr(reg1,ntrel1);
              Wordtostr(reg2,ntrel2);
              Wordtostr(reg3,ntrel3);
              Wordtostr(reg4,ntrel4);
              Wordtostr(reg5,ntrel5);
              Wordtostr(reg6,ntrel6);
     }
      void shedselectdis(){
              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
              Lcd_Out(1,1,"Next Shedule: S");
              Lcd_Out(1,16,shednon);
              Lcd_Out(2,1,"R1:");
              Lcd_Out(2,4,ntrel1);
              Lcd_Out(2,11,"R2:");
              Lcd_Out(2,14,ntrel2);
              Lcd_Out(3,1,"R3:");
              Lcd_Out(3,4,ntrel3);
              Lcd_Out(3,11,"R4:");
              Lcd_Out(3,14,ntrel4);
              Lcd_Out(4,1,"R5:");
              Lcd_Out(4,4,ntrel5);
              Lcd_Out(4,11,"R6:");
              Lcd_Out(4,14,ntrel6);
     }

     void editshed(){
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
                  Lcd_Out(1,1,"Edit Shedule: S");
                  Lcd_Out(1,16,shednon);
                  Lcd_Out(2,1,"R1:");
                  Lcd_Out(2,4,ntrel1);
                  Lcd_Out(2,11,"R2:");
                  Lcd_Out(2,14,ntrel2);
                  Lcd_Out(3,1,"R3:");
                  Lcd_Out(3,4,ntrel3);
                  Lcd_Out(3,11,"R4:");
                  Lcd_Out(3,14,ntrel4);
                  Lcd_Out(4,1,"R5:");
                  Lcd_Out(4,4,ntrel5);
                  Lcd_Out(4,11,"R6:");
                  Lcd_Out(4,14,ntrel6);
     }

     void relayssw(int x1, int x2, int x3, int x4, int x5, int x6){
              PORTA = 0b00000001;
              VDelay_ms(x1);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00000010;
              VDelay_ms(x2);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00000100;
              VDelay_ms(x3);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00001000;
              VDelay_ms(x4);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00010000;
              VDelay_ms(x5);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);

              PORTA = 0b00100000;
              VDelay_ms(x6);
              PORTA = 0b00000000;
              Delay_ms(50);
     }
      void disval(){
        Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
        findshed(0);
        Lcd_Out(1,1,"Shedule: S");
        Lcd_Out(1,11,shednon);
        Lcd_Out(2,1,"Count:");
        WordToStr(count, countn);
        Lcd_Out(2,1,"Count:");
        Lcd_Out(2,8,countn);
        Lcd_Out(3,1,"Steps:");
        Lcd_Out(4,1,"Temp:");
     }

    void main() {
      TRISA = 0b00000000;
      TRISB = 0b11111111;

      PORTA = 0b00000000;

      ADCON0=0;
      ADCON1=0X0F;
      CMCON=0X07;
      CCP1CON=0;
      CCP2CON=0;
      SSPCON1=0;


      Lcd_Init();
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
      Lcd_Out(1,6,"Welcome !");
      Delay_ms(2000);
      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
      disval();
      EEPROM_Write(0x00,255);
    /*for(i=1;i<131;i++){
       EEPROM_Write(i,i);
    Delay_ms(50);
      }*/
      while(1){
          if(PORTB.B7 = 1){  //proximity count
            Delay_ms(300);
            count++;
            disval();
          }
          //
          if(PORTB.B5 = 1){  //proximity count reset
            Delay_ms(300);
            Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
            Lcd_Out(1,1,"Reset Count?");
            WordToStr(count, countn);
            Lcd_Out(2,1,countn);
            Lcd_Out(3,1,"Press Enter to Reset");
            Lcd_Out(4,1,"Press Up to Back");
            while(1){
              if(PORTB.B4 = 1){ //enter
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  count=0;
                  disval();
                  break;
              }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){  //up
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  disval();
                  break;
              }
            }
          }
          //
          if(PORTB.B1 = 1){  //settings
             shedc = 0;
             Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
             Lcd_Out(1,1,"Select Shedule: S");
             findshed(0);
             Lcd_Out(1,18,shednon);
             Lcd_Out(2,1,"Select Set. to Back");
             Lcd_Out(3,1,"Select Enter to Edit");
             Lcd_Out(4,1,"Select Up or Down");
             Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FIRST_ROW);
             for(i=1;i<17;i++){
                Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
             }
             Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
             while(1){
                if(PORTB.B1 = 1){  //exit
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  disval();
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CURSOR_OFF);
                  break;
                }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){ //up button
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  if(shedno < 20){
                     shedc++;
                   }

                  findshed(shedc);
                  Lcd_Out(1,18,shednon);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FIRST_ROW);
                  for(i=1;i<17;i++){
                      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
                  }
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                }else if(PORTB.B3 = 1){ //down button
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  if(shedno > 1){
                     shedc--;
                   }

                  findshed(shedc);
                  Lcd_Out(1,18,shednon);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FIRST_ROW);
                  for(i=1;i<17;i++){
                      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
                  }
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                }else if(PORTB.B4 = 1){ //enter button
                  Delay_ms(300);
                  findshed(shedc);
                  shedrelay();
                  editshed();
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_SECOND_ROW);
                  Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                  while(1){
                     if(PORTB.B4 = 1){
                        Delay_ms(300);
                        Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_SECOND_ROW);
                        for(i=1;i<11;i++){
                           Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
                        }
                        Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                        while(1){
                            if(PORTB.B4 = 1){
                                Delay_ms(300);
                                Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_THIRD_ROW);
                                Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                                while(1){
                                   if(PORTB.B4 = 1){
                                      Delay_ms(300);
                                      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_THIRD_ROW);
                                      for(i=1;i<11;i++){
                                          Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
                                      }
                                      Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                                      while(1){
                                           if(PORTB.B4 = 1){
                                              Delay_ms(300);
                                              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FOURTH_ROW);
                                              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                                              while(1){ // POINTA
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                  if(PORTB.B4 = 1){
                                                     Delay_ms(300);
                                                     Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_FOURTH_ROW);
                                                     for(i=1;i<11;i++){
                                                          Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_MOVE_CURSOR_RIGHT);
                                                     }
                                                     Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_BLINK_CURSOR_ON);
                                                     while(1){

                                                     }
                                                   }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){//up

                                                   }else if(PORTB.B3 = 1){//down

                                                   }
------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                              }

                                            }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){//up

                                            }else if(PORTB.B3 = 1){//down

                                             }
                                      }
                                   }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){//up

                                   }else if(PORTB.B3 = 1){//down

                                   }
                                }
                            }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){//up

                            }else if(PORTB.B3 = 1){//down

                            }
                        }
                     }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){//up


                     }else if(PORTB.B3 = 1){//down


                     }

                  }
                }
             }
          }
          //
//POINT B
---------------------------------------------
           if((PORTB.B2 = 1)||(PORTB.B3 = 1)){ //up or down
              shedc = 0;
              Delay_ms(300);
              Lcd_Cmd(_LCD_CLEAR);
              findshed(0);
              Lcd_Out(1,1,"Runing: S");
              Lcd_Out(1,10,shednon);
              Lcd_Out(2,1,"Next:");
              Lcd_Out(3,1,"Press Up or Down Key");
              Lcd_Out(4,1,"Press Reset to Back");
              while(1){
                  if(PORTB.B3 = 1){ //down
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      if(shedno > 1){
                         shedc--;
                      }
                      findshed(shedc);
                      shedrelay();
                      shedselectdis();
                  }else if(PORTB.B2 = 1){ //up
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      if(shedno < 20){
                         shedc++;
                      }
                      findshed(shedc);
                      shedrelay();
                      shedselectdis();
                  }else if(PORTB.B4 = 1){ //enter
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      findshed(shedc);
                      EEPROM_Write(0x00,256-shedno);
                      disval();
                      break;
                  }else if(PORTB.B6 = 1){ //test
                       Delay_ms(300);
                       PORTC = 0b00000000;
                       Delay_ms(100);
                       relayssw(reg1, reg2, reg3, reg4, reg5,reg6);
                  }else if(PORTB.B5 = 1){ //reset
                      Delay_ms(300);
                      disval();
                      break;
                  }
              }
          }
------------------------------
          //

      }

    }
```

HEX Data:

```
EFC4    F004    0000    0000    EF00    F000    0000    0000
0000    0000    0000    0000    D7F3    FFFF    0E10    6E0D
2E0D    D7FE    0000    0012    0E08    6E0C    0E23    6E0D
2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    0012    0000    0012    6A08
0E08    6E0C    3400    3608    5004    5E08    B0D8    D002
2608    90D8    3600    2E0C    D7F5    0012    0101    BFBB
D002    9E83    D001    8E83    BDBB    D002    9C83    D001
8C83    BBBB    D002    9A83    D001    8A83    B9BB    D002
9883    D001    8883    B1A1    D002    8083    D001    9083
8283    DFD3    9283    B7BB    D002    9E83    D001    8E83
B5BB    D002    9C83    D001    8C83    B3BB    D002    9A83
D001    8A83    B1BB    D002    9883    D001    8883    B1A1
D002    8083    D001    9083    8283    DFB7    9283    A1A1
D002    DFAA    D001    DFA2    0012    0E22    6E0C    6A08
6A09    6A0A    6A0B    060C    B4D8    D01F    90D8    320B
320A    3209    3208    3203    3202    3201    3200    A0D8
D7F2    060C    B4D8    D009    5004    2608    5005    2209
5006    220A    5007    220B    D7EA    5004    2608    5005
2209    5006    220A    5007    220B    0012    0101    91A1
C1B5    F1BB    DF93    81A1    0012    9CA6    C1B5    FFA9
9EA6    80A6    CFA8    F000    0012    0101    6BB8    0E03
5DB8    E20A    51B8    25B6    6EE1    0E00    21B7    6EE2
0E20    6EE6    2BB8    D7F3    51B8    25B6    6EE1    0E00
21B7    6EE2    6AE6    07B8    51B8    25B6    6FB9    0E00
21B7    6FBA    0E0A    6E04    C1B5    F000    DF58    C008
F000    0E30    2600    C1B9    FFE1    C1BA    FFE2    C000
FFE6    0E0A    6E04    C1B5    F000    DF49    C000    F1B5
5000    0A00    E101    D002    07B8    D7DE    0012    6A08
6A09    0E10    6E0C    3401    3608    3609    5004    5E08
5005    A0D8    3C05    5E09    B0D8    D007    5004    2608
5005    B0D8    3C05    2609    90D8    3600    3601    2E0C
D7EA    0012    0EE8    0101    6FB0    0E03    6FB1    0E00
6FB2    6FB3    0EE8    6E00    0E03    6E01    0E00    6E02
0E00    6E03    C1AE    F004    C1AF    F005    0E00    6E06
6E07    DF5B    C000    F1B0    C001    F1B1    C002    F1B2
C003    F1B3    0E00    5C03    E108    0E00    5C02    E105
0E02    5C01    E102    0E94    5C00    E201    D031    0E94
5FB0    0E02    5BB1    0E00    5BB2    5BB3    0E05    6E00
5000    E007    33B3    33B2    33B1    33B0    9FB3    0FFF
D7F8    C1B0    F000    C1B1    F001    C1B2    F002    C1B3
F003    0E01    5FB0    0E00    5BB1    5BB2    5BB3    5000
1001    1002    1003    E00C    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    D7E1
0012    0101    6BB2    0E05    5DB2    E20A    51B2    25B0
6EE1    0E00    21B1    6EE2    0E20    6EE6    2BB2    D7F3
51B2    25B0    6EE1    0E00    21B1    6EE2    6AE6    07B2
51B2    25B0    6FB3    0E00    21B1    6FB4    0E0A    6E04
0E00    6E05    C1AE    F000    C1AF    F001    DF60    C008
F000    C009    F001    0E30    2600    C1B3    FFE1    C1B4
FFE2    C000    FFE6    0E0A    6E04    0E00    6E05    C1AE
F000    C1AF    F001    DF4B    C000    F1AE    C001    F1AF
0E00    1801    E102    0E00    1800    E101    D002    07B2
D7CF    0012    D010    0E80    0101    6FAE    D01A    0EC0
6FAE    D017    0E94    6FAE    D014    0ED4    6FAE    D011
0E80    6FAE    D00E    0101    51AE    0A01    E0EC    51AE
0A02    E0ED    51AE    0A03    E0ED    51AE    0A04    E0ED
D7EF    05AF    6E00    51AE    2600    C000    F1AE    C000
F1BB    DE64    91A1    6BB2    51B2    25B0    6EE9    0E00
21B1    6EEA    52EE    E00B    51B2    25B0    6EE9    0E00
21B1    6EEA    CFEE    F1B5    DEB9    2BB2    D7ED    81A1
0012    0101    6BB5    DEB9    C000    F03B    5000    0800
6E00    C000    F03B    51AE    2600    C000    F03B    C000
F1B5    0E6F    6FB6    0E01    6FB7    DEAF    0E06    023B
CFF3    F000    0E04    2600    C000    F19B    0E05    2400
6F9C    C000    F1B5    0E46    6FB6    0E00    6FB7    DE9D
C19C    F1B5    0E50    6FB6    0E00    6FB7    DE96    0012
0E01    0101    6FBB    DE1A    6BAE    DFCB    0E01    6FAE
0E01    6FAF    0E8E    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DF83    0E01
6FAE    0E0B    6FAF    0E6F    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DF7A
0E02    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0EA6    6FB0    0E00    6FB1
DF71    C0D9    F1AE    C0DA    F1AF    0ED3    6FB0    0E00
6FB1    DF1F    0E02    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0EAD    6FB0
0E00    6FB1    DF5F    0E02    6FAE    0E08    6FAF    0ED3
6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DF56    0E03    6FAE    0E01    6FAF
0E9F    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DF4D    0E04    6FAE    0E01
6FAF    0E99    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DF44    0012    0009
CFF5    FFE6    0600    E1FB    0601    E1F9    0012    9295
9095    9895    9A95    9C95    9E95    9283    9083    9E83
9C83    9A83    9883    DDA0    DD9F    DD9E    8A83    8883
8283    DDA3    9283    DD98    8283    DD9F    9283    DD94
8283    DD9B    9283    DD90    9883    8283    DD96    9283
DD8B    8283    DD92    9283    9A83    8E83    8283    DD8D
9283    DD82    9E83    8883    8283    DD87    9283    9883
8283    DD83    9283    DD78    8283    DD7F    9283    8883
8283    DD7B    9283    DD70    9883    8283    DD76    9283
8E83    8C83    8A83    8883    8283    DD6F    9283    DD64
0101    81A1    0012    0E01    0101    6FBB    DD77    0E01
6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E5F    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DEE2
0E01    6FAE    0E10    6FAF    0E6F    6FB0    0E01    6FB1
DED9    0E02    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E5B    6FB0    0E01
6FB1    DED0    0E02    6FAE    0E04    6FAF    0E51    6FB0
0E01    6FB1    DEC7    0E02    6FAE    0E0B    6FAF    0E57
6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DEBE    0E02    6FAE    0E0E    6FAF
0E73    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DEB5    0E03    6FAE    0E01
6FAF    0E87    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DEAC    0E03    6FAE
0E04    6FAF    0E8B    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DEA3    0E03
6FAE    0E0B    6FAF    0E83    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DE9A
0E03    6FAE    0E0E    6FAF    0E79    6FB0    0E01    6FB1
DE91    0E04    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E7F    6FB0    0E01
6FB1    DE88    0E04    6FAE    0E04    6FAF    0E4B    6FB0
0E01    6FB1    DE7F    0E04    6FAE    0E0B    6FAF    0E3C
6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DE76    0E04    6FAE    0E0E    6FAF
0E40    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DE6D    0012    A2A6    D002
0000    D7FC    9CA6    C1A2    FFA9    C1A3    FFA8    9EA6
84A6    CFF2    F000    9EF2    0E55    6EA7    0EAA    6EA7
82A6    BE00    D002    9EF2    D001    8EF2    94A6    0012
0E01    6E80    C1A2    F1AE    C1A3    F1AF    DDA3    6A80
0E41    6E0C    0EEE    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC
0000    0E02    6E80    C1A4    F1AE    C1A5    F1AF    DD92
6A80    0E41    6E0C    0EEE    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C
D7FC    0000    0E04    6E80    C1A6    F1AE    C1A7    F1AF
DD81    6A80    0E41    6E0C    0EEE    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE
2E0C    D7FC    0000    0E08    6E80    C1A8    F1AE    C1A9
F1AF    DD70    6A80    0E41    6E0C    0EEE    6E0D    2E0D
D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    0000    0E10    6E80    C1AA    F1AE
C1AB    F1AF    DD5F    6A80    0E41    6E0C    0EEE    6E0D
2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    0000    0E20    6E80    C1AC
F1AE    C1AD    F1AF    DD4E    6A80    0E41    6E0C    0EEE
6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    0000    0012    0E01
0101    6FBB    DC73    0E0C    6FBB    DC70    0E01    6FAE
0E01    6FAF    0E15    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DDDB    0E01
6FAE    0E10    6FAF    0E6F    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DDD2
0E02    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E31    6FB0    0E00    6FB1
DDC9    0E02    6FAE    0E04    6FAF    0E51    6FB0    0E01
6FB1    DDC0    0E02    6FAE    0E0B    6FAF    0E35    6FB0
0E00    6FB1    DDB7    0E02    6FAE    0E0E    6FAF    0E73
6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DDAE    0E03    6FAE    0E01    6FAF
0E2D    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DDA5    0E03    6FAE    0E04
6FAF    0E8B    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DD9C    0E03    6FAE
0E0B    6FAF    0E25    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DD93    0E03
6FAE    0E0E    6FAF    0E79    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DD8A
0E04    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E29    6FB0    0E00    6FB1
DD81    0E04    6FAE    0E04    6FAF    0E4B    6FB0    0E01
6FB1    DD78    0E04    6FAE    0E0B    6FAF    0EDB    6FB0
0E00    6FB1    DD6F    0E04    6FAE    0E0E    6FAF    0E40
6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DD66    0012    0101    6BA0    C19B
F19F    519F    5D9C    E321    0E4A    6FA2    0E00    6FA3
51A0    27A2    B0D8    2BA3    C19F    F1B5    DC4E    C1A2
FFE1    C1A3    FFE2    C000    FFE6    0E82    6E0C    0EDD
6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    0000    0000    0E06
5DA0    A0D8    2BA0    2B9F    D7DC    504A    2439    6E00
0E00    203A    6E01    C000    F19D    C001    F19E    504B
2439    6F97    0E00    203A    6F98    504C    2439    6F99
0E00    203A    6F9A    504D    2439    6F95    0E00    203A
6F96    504E    2439    6F91    0E00    203A    6F92    504F
2439    6F93    0E00    203A    6F94    C000    F1AE    C001
F1AF    0E51    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DCC3    C197    F1AE
C198    F1AF    0E73    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DCBA    C199
F1AE    C19A    F1AF    0E8B    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DCB1
C195    F1AE    C196    F1AF    0E79    6FB0    0E01    6FB1
DCA8    C191    F1AE    C192    F1AF    0E4B    6FB0    0E01
6FB1    DC9F    C193    F1AE    C194    F1AF    0E40    6FB0
0E00    6FB1    DC96    0012    ECC0    F008    6A92    0EFF
6E93    6A80    6AC2    0E0F    6EC1    0E07    6EB4    6ABD
6ABA    6AC6    DD94    0E01    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E0C
6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E01    6FAE    0E06    6FAF    0EDF
6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DCBE    0E0B    6E0B    0E26    6E0C
0E5D    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA
0000    0000    0E01    6FBB    EC2E    F000    DD19    6BA2
0EFF    6FA3    DE3B    8E81    AE81    D010    0E02    6E0B
0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC
2E0B    D7FA    0100    4BD9    2BDA    DD02    8A81    AA81
D064    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    0101
2E0D    D7FD    2E0C    D7FB    2E0B    D7F9    0E01    6FBB
EC2E    F000    0E01    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0EC6    6FB0
0E00    6FB1    DC77    C0D9    F1AE    C0DA    F1AF    0ED3
6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DC25    0E02    6FAE    0E01    6FAF
0ED3    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DC65    0E03    6FAE    0E01
6FAF    0EE9    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    DC5C    0E04    6FAE
0E01    6FAF    0E39    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DC53    8881
A881    D011    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D
2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    0100    6BD9
6BDA    DCAE    D012    8481    A481    D00E    0E02    6E0B
0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC
2E0B    D7FA    DC9D    D001    D7DA    8281    A281    D1A0
0101    6B4A    0E01    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E01    6FAE
0E01    6FAF    0E27    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    DC1B    6BAE
DC58    0E01    6FAE    0E12    6FAF    0E6F    6FB0    0E01
6FB1    DC10    0E02    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0EFE    6FB0
0E00    6FB1    DC07    0E03    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E12
6FB0    0E01    6FB1    ECA2    F001    0E04    6FAE    0E01
6FAF    0EB4    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    ECA2    F001    0E80
6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E01    0100    6F83    0E11    5D83
E208    0E14    0101    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0100    2B83
D7F5    0E0F    0101    6FBB    EC2E    F000    8281    A281
D012    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D
D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    DC3A    0E0C    6FBB
EC2E    F000    D13D    8481    A481    D037    0E02    6E0B
0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC
2E0B    D7FA    0E14    5C3B    E202    0101    2B4A    C14A
F1AE    ECE1    F001    0E01    6FAE    0E12    6FAF    0E6F
6FB0    0E01    6FB1    ECA2    F001    0E80    6FBB    EC2E
F000    0E01    0100    6F83    0E11    5D83    E208    0E14
0101    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0100    2B83    D7F5    0E0F
0101    6FBB    EC2E    F000    D102    8681    A681    D037
0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE
2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    503B    0801    E202    0101
074A    C14A    F1AE    ECE1    F001    0E01    6FAE    0E12
6FAF    0E6F    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    ECA2    F001    0E80
6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E01    0100    6F83    0E11    5D83
E208    0E14    0101    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0100    2B83
D7F5    0E0F    0101    6FBB    EC2E    F000    D0C8    8881
A881    D0C5    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D
2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    C14A    F1AE
ECE1    F001    DDDA    DD53    0EC0    6FBB    EC2E    F000
0E0F    6FBB    EC2E    F000    8881    A881    D0A7    0E02
6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    0101    2E0D    D7FD
2E0C    D7FB    2E0B    D7F9    0EC0    6FBB    EC2E    F000
0E01    0100    6F83    0E0B    5D83    E208    0E14    0101
6FBB    EC2E    F000    0100    2B83    D7F5    0E0F    0101
6FBB    EC2E    F000    8881    A881    D07F    0E02    6E0B
0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    0101    2E0D    D7FD    2E0C
D7FB    2E0B    D7F9    0E94    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E0F
6FBB    EC2E    F000    8881    A881    D066    0E02    6E0B
0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    0101    2E0D    D7FD    2E0C
D7FB    2E0B    D7F9    0E94    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E01
0100    6F83    0E0B    5D83    E208    0E14    0101    6FBB
EC2E    F000    0100    2B83    D7F5    0E0F    0101    6FBB
EC2E    F000    8881    A881    D03E    0E02    6E0B    0E86
6E0C    0E99    6E0D    0101    2E0D    D7FD    2E0C    D7FB
2E0B    D7F9    0ED4    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E0F    6FBB
EC2E    F000    8881    A881    D025    0E02    6E0B    0E86
6E0C    0E99    6E0D    0101    2E0D    D7FD    2E0C    D7FB
2E0B    D7F9    0ED4    6FBB    EC2E    F000    0E01    0100
6F83    0E0B    5D83    E208    0E14    0101    6FBB    EC2E
F000    0100    2B83    D7F5    0E0F    0101    6FBB    EC2E
F000    D7FF    D7D7    D7BE    D796    D77D    D755    D6AE
8481    B481    D004    8681    B681    D001    D0E1    0101
6B4A    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D
D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    0E01    6FBB    EC2E
F000    6BAE    ECE1    F001    0E01    6FAE    0E01    6FAF
0E84    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    ECA2    F001    0E01    6FAE
0E0A    6FAF    0E6F    6FB0    0E01    6FB1    ECA2    F001
0E02    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E7D    6FB0    0E00    6FB1
ECA2    F001    0E03    6FAE    0E01    6FAF    0E54    6FB0
0E00    6FB1    ECA2    F001    0E04    6FAE    0E01    6FAF
0E69    6FB0    0E00    6FB1    ECA2    F001    8681    A681
D018    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D
D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    503B    0801    A0D8
074A    C14A    F1AE    ECE1    F001    DCBF    ECB3    F002
D07E    8481    A481    D018    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C
0E99    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA
0E14    5C3B    A0D8    2B4A    C14A    F1AE    ECE1    F001
DCA4    ECB3    F002    D063    8881    A881    D019    0E02
6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C
D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    C14A    F1AE    ECE1    F001    6BA2
503B    0800    6FA3    EC36    F003    EC10    F002    D048
8C81    AC81    D032    0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99
6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    6A82
0E82    6E0C    0EDD    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE    2E0C    D7FC
0000    0000    C19D    F1A2    C19E    F1A3    C197    F1A4
C198    F1A5    C199    F1A6    C19A    F1A7    C195    F1A8
C196    F1A9    C191    F1AA    C192    F1AB    C193    F1AC
C194    F1AD    EC50    F003    D012    8A81    AA81    D00F
0E02    6E0B    0E86    6E0C    0E99    6E0D    2E0D    D7FE
2E0C    D7FC    2E0B    D7FA    EC10    F002    D001    D766
D4FA    D7FF    6445    7469    5320    6568    7564    656C
203A    0053    3452    003A    3552    003A    3352    003A
3152    003A    3252    003A    03E8    5200    3A36    0000
0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000    5000    6572    7373    5520    2070    726F    4420
776F    206E    654B    0079    7250    7365    2073    6552
6573    2074    6F74    4220    6361    006B    654E    7478
003A    5200    6E75    6E69    3A67    5320    5300    6568
7564    656C    203A    0053    6554    706D    003A    7453
7065    3A73    4300    756F    746E    003A    6F43    6E75
3A74    5300    6C65    6365    2074    7055    6F20    2072
6F44    6E77    5200    7365    7465    4320    756F    746E
003F    0000    0000    0000    0000    3652    003A    6557
636C    6D6F    2065    0021    7250    7365    2073    6E45
6574    2072    6F74    5220    7365    7465    5300    6C65
6365    2074    6553    2E74    7420    206F    6142    6B63
5300    6C65    6365    2074    6E45    6574    2072    6F74
4520    6964    0074    6553    656C    7463    5320    6568
7564    656C    203A    0053    7250    7365    2073    7055
7420    206F    6142    6B63    0000    0000    0000    0000
0000    0000    0000    3252    003A    3152    003A    654E
7478    5320    6568    7564    656C    203A    0053    0000
0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    0000    3552
003A    3452    003A    3352    003A    0000    0000    0000
EE10    F015
```

Comment: It's a PIC, always suspect stack overflow. Apart from that, I doubt anyone will be able to help unless you can narrow down the problem much more.

Comment: I added protius simulation error. I think it is reseting.

Comment: There you go then, stack overflow like I guessed. When small changes to code causes the program to behave randomly. stack overflow is often the culprit. PIC are infamous for their crappy stacks and burdensome limits in function call depth.

Comment: Btw if you have a decent debugger where you can see what C code that ended up at address 0x098E, you can see exactly which line that caused the bug. If not, you have to dig through the linker map file to see which function that's allocated around 0x098E.

Comment: I only can see HEX file then how to find out in C code?

Comment: You should have a "map file" somewhere, or the option to generate one by the linker. It will tell you which functions that are allocated at which flash memory address. Alternatively, you could just try to single-step through the program until you find the crash.

Comment: I can not find 098E in HEX file.

Comment: I updated HEX data.

Comment: 0x98E was the value of the PC at the program crash. The function where it occurred does not necessary start at that exact address, but rather the crash would happen in the middle of the function somewhere. For example if you have function `foo` allocated at address 0x980, the crash would happen 0xE = 14 instructions into that function.

Comment: Can't you find out error by the above details?

Comment: No, it is just hex gibberish. Also, it isn't obvious if this is a stack overflow caused by filling the return call stack, or by filling the application stack.

Comment: Please transfer this question to stackoverflow. I do not have Reputation for that

Comment: Only moderators can do that. But it's perfectly fine to post firmware questions here. I think you'll find more PIC experts on EE than on SO. The problem is that none can trouble-shoot this bug but you, so the question isn't really answerable on any site.

Comment: When I remove POINT B part and Add POINT A part to code Then Working. When I do another way then also working. When I remove POINT A  part and Add POINT B part to code.Why is that?

Comment: Because, again, you have a stack overflow? And such bugs result in random behavior. Although, I noticed that you have code like `PORTB.B2 = 1)||(PORTB.B3 = 1)` where you probably meant to write `==`. Any half-decent compiler would give a warning here. The various Microchip compilers have a very poor reputation, so I wouldn't count on it to warn.